# Databind Combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to databind a combobox in WPF for the first time and I can't get it to happen.

The image below shows my code, can you please tell me what I am missing?  I only want graphic stuff in the xaml.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Patient p = new Patient();
    this.cbPatient.DataContext = p.SelfListAll();
    this.cbPatient.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    this.cbPatient.SelectedValuePath = "PatientIDInternal";
}
```

...

[image]

Comment: In future questions please copy/paste code where possible rather than adding screenshots.  It makes it more searchable for people with the same question, and easier for people to copy/paste your code into editors and get you an answer more quickly.  I left the watch window part because it is valid screenshot material.

Comment: Ok, good point, will do.

Answer (score 2):

**Short explanation:** Just make the following change to your XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=patientList}" />
```

Then, in your `Window_Loaded` event handler, just add

```
this.DataContext = this
```

Then make a new member called `patientList` of type `ObservableCollection<Patient>`.

---

**Long explanation:**

You don't have a binding set up. You need to create one through XAML like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=patientList}" />
```

Then, the combobox will look for a member or property called "patientList" on the object that is set as its `DataContext`. I'd recommend using an ObservableCollection for `patientList`.

Alternatively, to create one in code, you can follow the examples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#specifying_the_binding_source

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("patientList");
myBinding.DataContext = someObject; //whatever object has 'patientList' as a member
mycombobox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

This will set a binding on the `mycombobox` ComboBox with a path of `patientList` and a DataContext of `someObject`. In other words, `mycombobox` will show the contents of `someObject.patientList` (which would ideally be some ObservableCollection, so that updates to the collection notify the binding to update).

Comment: Would you happen to have an answer for a combobox?  Thanks.

Comment: Clarified example to use a combobox.

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to avoid having any binding logic in the xaml.  I only want the graphic designer to be in there and the only point of sharable information is the name of the control.

Comment: The entire point of the WPF M-V-VM model is to have the view be editable completely separate from the code (model) with very loose coupling, enabled by the `{Binding}` syntax. Your graphic designer will still see the entire layout and will even gain knowledge of which controls get populated by what entities, such as your `{Binding patientList}` binding. It may seem foreign to you when you're getting started, but using `{Binding}` syntax in XAML is really how WPF was designed to work :)

Comment: One reason why setting bindings from code is coupled more tightly to the view and is thus harder to maintain: you have to name controls in the view and then hardcode these names in your code. What if your designer decides that it makes more sense to use a `ListBox` instead of a `ComboBox` in XAML? You will have to change your code (in likely many places) to use a ListBox, (with a different name, such as `lbPatient`.) Not so with a binding in XAML: your designer changes the `<ComboBox ...` to a `<ListBox ... ` and keeps the same `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=patientList}"`. Nothing else changes.

Comment: As Jason Dolinger mentions in [his excellent M-V-VM tutorial](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650), "you know you're on the right track if you almost never have to name your controls."

Comment: Aphex, thank you for your thoughts as these are the issues I am thinking about right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually add the binding, e.g.:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = MySourceObject;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("MyPropertyPath");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(cbPatient, SomeDependencyProperty, binding);
```

Comment: What goes in MyPropertyPath and what goes in SomeDependencyProperty?  Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell from your code above.  I can tell you that SomeDependencyProperty is the property you want to bind to and MyPropertyPath is the property you want to pull from.  For example, if I wanted a TextBox to display a field "MyName" from a class, then MyPropertyPath would be MyName, and SomeDependencyProperty would be TextBox.TextProperty.

Comment: I'm trying to fill a combobox.

Comment: Meaning you are setting the ItemsSource of the ComboBox?  That would mean that the property to set (SomeDependencyProperty) was ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty.  The MyPropertyPath would be the property you wanted to use to fill the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ItemsSource property relative to the DataContext:

```
cbPatient.SetBinding(ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

**EDIT**

The ItemsSource property of the ComboBox is the property that should point to the collection of items to be shown.

The collection you are interested in, is in the DataContext.

The Binding is an object that keeps track of changes of the collection and reports them to the ComboBox and its Path is relative to the object in the DataContext.

Because the Binding also needs to know the ComboBox you use the static SetBinding method that ties the connection between ComboBox and the Binding.

As in your code the collection itself is in the DataContext, the Path is empty.

The ItemsSource property should point to the collection of Patients. Because the collection of Patients is already in the DataContext, the Binding's Path property is empty.

Suppose an class named Hospital has two properties: Patients and Docters (and perhaps more: Rooms, Appointments, ...) and you set the DataContext of the ComboBox to an instance of Hospital. Then you would have to set the Binding's Path Property to "Patients"

Now the ComboBox will display each item (Patient) in the collection. To specify how a single Patient should be displayed you need to set the ItemTemplate property of the ComboBox.

Comment: Is it possible to flesh this out a bit, I'm a little lost here.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMalter, Added some clarification.

Comment: I'm sorry Emo, I am just not getting this.  What goes in ItemsSourceProperty?  I don't understand the explination as I am new to this.  Is there something in my Patient class I put in there?  What goes in there?  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMalter, I added more to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the answer to how to populate a combobox in WPF.  First, thanks to everyone above who made suggestions.  The part I was missing was that I was not populating the ItemsSource property but the DataContext property.  Again, thanks to everyone for their help.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Patient p = new Patient();
    this.cbPatient.ItemsSource = p.SelfListAll();
    this.cbPatient.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    this.cbPatient.SelectedValuePath = "PatientIDInternal";
    this.cbPatient.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: this is no real databinding. you just set the itemssource directly. you should really read some stuff about wpf databinding model first. just to get the big advance of it.

Comment: It does serve my purpose.  That said, I am new to WPF and might not have the best ideas about it, but I only want the graphic designer in the xaml file, not developers.  The only sharable piece of information is the name of the control.  Developers will stay in C# code and designers will work in the xaml.  How practical that is, or even if that is a good idea or not, I am not sure of, but that is my thinking to date.